# How to convert this for loop C# code to Linq or make the process time faster?

Tags: c#, linq

[Convert this for loop C# code to Linq or make the process time faster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zk7da.jpg)

```
List<List<Array_Group>> array_Group = new List<List<Array_Group>>();
array_Group.Add(new List<Array_Group>());
object previosSelecter = null;

for (int i = 0; i < array_count; i++)
{
    Type Group = typeof(Array_Group);
    var current = after_Rounded.ElementAt(i);

    Type type = current.GetType();

    PropertyInfo prop = Group.GetProperty("FD_T_Act_");           

    object currentSelector = prop.GetValue(current);
    if (previosSelecter == null)
    {
        array_Group.LastOrDefault().Add(current);
    }
    else
        if (currentSelector.Equals(previosSelecter))
        {
            array_Group.LastOrDefault().Add(current);
        }
        else
        {
            array_Group.Add(new List<Array_Group>() { current });
        }
    previosSelecter = currentSelector;
}
```

The execution time takes very long time due to the huge data that needs to be processed.
How can I make it more simpler and faster execution?

Comment: linq wouldn't make it faster, but it might simplify your code.

Comment: As one of the way to improve performance is try to avoid using `after_Rounded.ElementAt(i)`. As far as I know it has `O(n)`. Use, instead, `List<T>` and access by index, then it will be `O(1)`

Comment: @BigB Have you considered parallel processing? It could be beneficial if you could divide your source data into smaller chunks and process them simultaneously.

Comment: You use the value of property `FD_T_Act_`, is that for the example, or is that the only property you want to use as currentSelector?

Comment: @PeterCsala sure i will look forward into parallel processing, thank you.

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: [ask] and [mre] may be important here we have just a block of code and "Make it faster". No context, clear requirement, no benchmark, no reproduction. And the minimal simplification part of the Mre is important . We can just look at the code and comment on what we see. What if the changes should to be made on the approch it self. EG: imagine a car on a race circuit, We only see the lap and talk the trajectory. But if the goal was to get to the stand from the starting line, the shortest way is not to make a full lap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two lines

```
Type Group = typeof(Array_Group);

PropertyInfo prop = Group.GetProperty("FD_T_Act_");
```

You can definitly move before your loop. This is a constant expression, will result in always the same value, but it's a very expensive time consuming expression also.

Accessing a property via 'GetProperty' is also quiet time consuming.

You can create a delegate to improve this (also before your loop)

```
 Func<Array_Group, propType> getter = (Func<Array_Group, propType>)
        Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<Array_Group, propType>), null,
            prop.GetGetMethod());
```

It's also typesafe, it returns your real datatype, not just an object, in case of it is a value type, you avoid the boxing with such a delegate.

So instead of

```
 object currentSelector = prop.GetValue(current);
```

You do

```
 propType currentSelector = getter(current);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

var array_Group = after_Rounded.GroupBy(x => (x as Array_Group)?.FD_T_Act_);
```

This will produce a `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Linq.IGrouping<string, T>>` where T is whatever is inside your `after_Rounded`.

Comment: Thank you, is there anything that i can do to change this if (previosSelecter == null)

Comment: @BigB can you give a sample of source data and expected data